# Stdout from python script apparently redirected in cron

Tags: python, email, cron, stdout, setup.py

Running into an interesting issue, have a python file that I have installed using setup.py. I want to send the output(just prints to stdout) of this python script as the body of an email. When piping this script to mail on the command line, like below, all is well:

`my_python_script | mail -s "my subject" my_email`

However, when the same script is added to the crontab, it yields the expected subject, but an empty body:

`* * * * * my_python_script | mail -s "my subject" my_email`

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Are you using complete path to the script?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem; is it with the script or with the cron line? To determine this, simplify the script down to just one line: `print "hello, world"`. Does it still fail in cron?

Comment: @AnandSKumar it appears that that was the problem, `my_python_script` was set as an entry point, so setting the command as `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/my_python_script | mail -s "my subject" my_email` solved the problem.

Comment: @Robᵩ yes, all the script doing was printing hello world.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put the python interpreter before your script name, like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/python my_python_script | mail -s "my subject" my_email
```

You can find the location of the python interpreter by using the `which python` command.  Replace `/bin/python` with this path.

Comment: The problem was actually a result of not being able to find the entry point, as opposed to not being able to find the python interpreter.

Comment: Glad you found it.  Hopefully this answer will help someone else.